# wsgi + Django: SOAPpy(pyXML) modules Import Error

Tags: python, django, soappy, django-wsgi

In the command line the code works perfect,
but throw import error when use **django + mod_python or wsgi +apache**

The message is:

```
ImportError at /test2/

DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response

D:\dgwww\mytest\views.py in test2

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\SOAPpy\wstools\WSDLTools.py in loadFromStream

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\dom\minidom.py in parse

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\dom\expatbuilder.py in <module>

C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\parsers\expat.py in <module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved.
I down load PyXML 0.8.4 for Python 2.6 win32 from

http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2009/10/31/windows-installer-for-pyxml-0-8-4-for-python-2-6-x/

and copy the files to python's site_packages